# DevExtreme React - position of $ character changes from end of string to start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, devexpress, devextreme-react

For some reason the “~!#%$$”:“ symbols appear in the start of the **text** property of CheckBox component even if I add them in the end of the string when **rtlEnabled** is on.
I assume that the purpose of rtlEnabled is to switch positions of the checkbox and the label, not the composition of the string.

I've tried to track the problem but without any luck yet...

It can be reproduced easily from [here](https://js.devexpress.com/React/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/CheckBox/Overview/MaterialBlueLight/)

edit the code from the example like this
[image: img1]

the result is this: &test, instead of test&

[image: img2]

**Found a solution:**

adding:

```
.dx-checkbox-text {
    direction: ltr;
  }
```

is fixing the direction issue for the label/text of the checkbox.
the **dx-checkbox-text**  is inheriting the **rtl** from the parent or something similar I guess.

Comment: Some examples on https://js.devexpress.com/React/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Common/EditorsRightToLeftSupport/MaterialBlueLight/, by changing the dropdown to Arabic right to left and then typing stuff in the "Text" input, it seems to place punctuation at the start and move the position of the cursor randomly while typing.  Very strange.  Possibly how RTL is supposed to work but I doubt it.